# C - Linked list printing extra link

Tags: arrays, c, debugging, linked-list, malloc

My program is printing one more link, at the beginning, than what I'm supposed to have. I can't find the problem in my debugging.

Also, I'm unsure if my sorting is optimal.

I've added the text I'm testing with, I should have in total 26 links but I'm getting 27.

```
NEWLY CHAINER READ ELEMENTS KAFKA YOUNG IS WELL SKILLED ZAPPED AT
PUBLISHED METAMORPHOSIS IMAGINE HIS A FRANCHISE WHEN WORLDWAR RAGEID VANQUISHED
TUBERCULOSIS XENOPHOBIA YET GREATLY ULTIMATELY
```

I know the problem is happening at init_and_sort_link().

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
const int FILEWORDNUMBER = 46;

struct link {
    char *word;
    struct link *next;
};

void init_and_sort_link(char **words, struct link *head) {
   for (int i = 0; i < FILEWORDNUMBER; ++i) {
      if (words[i] != 0) {
         struct link *temp;
         temp = head;
         temp = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
         temp->word = words[i];
         temp->next = NULL;

         if (strcmp(head->word, temp->word) < 0) {
            temp->next = head;
         } else {
            struct link *cur = head;
            while (cur->next != NULL &&
                   strcmp(temp->word, cur->next->word) >= 0) {
               cur = cur->next;
            }
            temp->next = cur->next;
            cur->next = temp;
         }
      }
   }
}

void readLine(FILE *file, char **words) {
   int i = 0;
   char ligne[80];
   while (fgets(ligne, 80, file)) {
      char *word = strtok(ligne, " ,.-\n");
      while (word != NULL) {
         words[(i)++] = strdup(word);
         word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-\n");
      }
   }
   fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   char **words = calloc(FILEWORDNUMBER, 30 * sizeof(char *) + 1);
   readLine(file, words);
   struct link *head = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
   struct link *ptrr = head;
   //head->word = words[0];
   head->next = NULL;
   init_and_sort_link(words, head);
   int a = 0;
   while (ptrr != NULL) {
      printf("Link#%d ->%s\n", a, ptrr->word);
      ptrr = ptrr->next;
      a++;
   }
   struct link *tmpp;
   while (head != NULL) {
      tmpp = head;
      head = head->next;
      free(tmpp);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < FILEWORDNUMBER; ++i) {
      free(words[i]);
   }
   free(words);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This memory allocation char **words = calloc(3, 30 * sizeof(char *) + 1); does not make a sense.

Comment: is that your actual input file, 3 lines of space separated text?

Comment: @pm100 yes. It's that's it. I know where you're coming from. I've got the words count from my file covered in my real code. It's been hard coded as FILEWORDNUMBER.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes. I forgot to change it with the constant. I fixed it.

Comment: @LIsa The problem is not in the constant. This expression 30 * sizeof(char *) + 1 does not make a sense.

Comment: regarding:            `const int FILEWORDNUMBER = 46;`  however, there are only 26 words in your file

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are a couple of things wrong here

First

Words is an array of pointers to strings, so it must be allocated like this

```
 char **words = calloc(FILEWORDNUMBER, sizeof(char *));
```

The `30*sizeof(char*) + 1)` seems to be an effort to reserve space for strings. Not needed yet.

Second in init_and_sort_link we have

```
     struct link *temp;
     temp = head;  <<<<=== this line is meaningless as its overwritten by the next line
     temp = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
     temp->word = words[i];
     temp->next = NULL;

     if (strcmp(head->word, temp->word) < 0) {
```

The strcmp fails becuase head->word has not been set to anything. I am not sure what you want here tho

I can see that you commented out a line that would have inialized `head->word` in main. I see your problem now that I put that line back

I would change the structure of you program so that you do not create the head before calling the int_sort. Instead create all the links in that function and have it return the head to main.

Comment: ok. Ive been debugging and now I see what you meant. Basically if the new word to link alphabetically comes before the first one. Then it becomes the first one.

Comment: @LIsa see edit at the end

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, great thanks for the feedback, youre a quick analyzer.